# Change the axis units on a histogram using seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, histogram, seaborn

I'm working on the boston housing project of the udacity ML nano degree which use the following [data set](https://github.com/udacity/machine-learning/blob/master/projects/boston_housing/housing.csv):

I'm using seabron to plot an histogram of the data:

```
df = pd.read_csv('housing.csv')
sns.distplot(df['MEDV'])
```

[image]

Which looks ok, but I don't like the scale of the axis, it's hard to read.
How can I set the x axis on thousands and for Y axis 10e-3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this using matplotlib.pyplot.ticklabel_format:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv('housing.csv')
g = sns.distplot(df['MEDV'])  
plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='both', scilimits=(0,0))
```

[image: Output Image]

Let me know if that's what you were looking for! And good luck!

Comment: How is related g = sns.distplot(df['MEDV']) with plt.ticklabel_format() ? I don't see g anywhere else?

Comment: I believe that it just changes the default ticklabel format for all matplotlib plots. For example, if you run the `plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='both', scilimits=(0,0)` at the very beginning of the code, it works the same way. More of a settings change than a graph change.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply divide the series by 100 i.e

```
sns.distplot(df['MEDV']/100)
plt.show()
```

[image]
Hope it helps